# 'cocos' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, android, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to create my first ever Cocos2d project, but it isn't going too well. I know this has been asked and answered many times. Still I kind find the right solution for myself. When creating new project I get the "cocos is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". I have already restarted cmd and computer. Here is some pictures to show that all the enviroment variables are found. I have cocos2d-x-3.9.
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows users must first go to the path

```
cd cocos2d-x-3.9\tools\cocos2d-console\bin
```

and then execute

```
cocos new -l js helloApp -d C:\Users\...\Android\helloApp
```

More about creating new project you can find [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if the user has admin permissions, the location of cocos.py executable (in this case `C:\Users\<blanked out username>\Android\cocos2d-x-3.9\tools\cocos2d-console\bin`) can be added to the system PATH variable. Windows will then recognise cocos.py from wherever.